# python : could not get threaded class instance to work

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I tried to make a thread, in order to launch serval instances of my class at the same time. They are supposed to write metrics every x secounds..
But at the moment, the metrics are only written once !

I tried to adapt following examples :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm
http://python.developpez.com/faq/?page=Thread

```
class tcSensor(Thread):
    """

    """
    name=""
    label=""
    adapterID=""
    channel=""
    polling_interval=1
    temperature = 0
    ambient = 0
    state =1
    temperatureSensor=object

    def __init__(self,temperatureSensor,name,label,adapterID,channel,polling_interval):
        super(tcSensor, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.cancelled = False
        self.temperatureSensor
        self.name = name
        self.label = label
        self.adapterID=adapterID
        self.channel=channel
        self.polling_interval=polling_interval

    def run(self):
        while not self.cancelled:
            self.update()
            sleep(0.1)    

    def cancel(self):
        """End this timer thread"""
        self.cancelled = True

    def update(self):
        print "--update--"
        self.ambient=temperatureSensor.getAmbientTemperature()
        self.temperature=temperatureSensor.getTemperature(self.channel)
        logger.info("%s: ambient=%f sensor=%f" % (self.name,self.ambient,self.temperature))
        pass

# Read config file
Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read("./thermocouple.config")
i=0
sensor=[]
for section in Config.sections():
    print ("configuring input %s" % section)
    mysensor=(tcSensor(temperatureSensor,section,Config.get(section,"description"),Config.getint(section,"adapterID"),Config.getint(section,"channel"),Config.getfloat(section,"polling_interval")))
    mysensor.daemon= True
    mysensor.start()
    sensor.append(mysensor)
```

Comment: You have a bunch of class attributes that are masked by your instance attributes.  Get rid of the class ones.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand that could you explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're daemonizing your thread, which means that the thread will not stop the interpreter from exiting. After you start the thread, there's nothing left to do, so your program terminates.

Try adding something like the following to the bottom of your code:

```
while True:
    sleep(0.1)
```

Your program will keep executing until you hit Ctrl-C. Your threads don't seem to have any clean up, but if you added some you could wrap that sleep loop in a try/except and cancel your thread:

```
try:
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    for s in sensor:
        s.cancel()
    for s in sensor:
        s.join()
```